# how can i create the customize image with hadoop installation for openstack?

Tags: 12.04, openstack

I have used ubuntu builder to make iso image but it works only vmware .The image is not working on openstack. can you please help for make image for openstack with hadoop installation?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a clean Ubuntu server instance, [install Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/quickstart.html) in it and see if I can make a snapshot from it and easily instantiate new ones (maybe write a script for the changes if it's not too hard).

If you want something automatic, you can try installing Juju and hook it up to OpenStack as a provider - it has Hadoop charms. Also, [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/409203/deploy-hadoop-to-openstack) might be of interest to you.